# anaconda - using conda create

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a basic question about using Conda  as an environment manager.

I understand that it is considered good practice  to create an environment using "conda create -n myenv"  and install there new packages or different versions of packages, because this way I can be certain that I run my code with the same versions.

However, when I create a new environment, it is created empty, without any of the packages anaconda comes with . How can I start the new enviroment with all the installed anaconda packages ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have to install anaconda package like following:

```
 conda create -n myEnv anaconda
```

when you add `anaconda` to  your command you tell conda to install all package thats come with anaconda

Comment: This no longer works! Just tried and no matplotlib, numpy, or scipy. Bummer! Why remove such a useful feature?

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create -n myEnv python=3.6
```

That should include all the default packages in your environment. Having said that, I do think it's good practice to only have packages installed that you actually need. Do you really require everything conda includes as default?

EDIT: Ok I just double checked and conda really doesn't include as much as I thought. Here is the list of default packages for a python 3.6 env:

```
ca-certificates: 2018.4.16-0       conda-forge
certifi:         2018.4.16-py36_0  conda-forge
libgcc-ng:       7.2.0-hdf63c60_3             
ncurses:         5.9-10            conda-forge
openssl:         1.0.2o-0          conda-forge
pip:             9.0.3-py36_0      conda-forge
python:          3.6.5-1           conda-forge
readline:        7.0-0             conda-forge
setuptools:      39.2.0-py36_0     conda-forge
sqlite:          3.20.1-2          conda-forge
tk:              8.6.7-0           conda-forge
wheel:           0.31.0-py36_0     conda-forge
xz:              5.2.3-0           conda-forge
zlib:            1.2.11-h470a237_3 conda-forge
```